# Update row with values of other column's row of same Table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table:-

```
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
 | IsActive | IsFirstChunk | TotalResponseTime | StallTime |
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
 | Yes      | Yes          | 62                | NULL      |
 | NULL     | NULL         | 327               | 0         |
 | NULL     | NULL         | 59                | 0         |
```

I want to fill the row of the column StallTime with value of TotalResponseTime only for the row whose column IsActive and IsFirstChunk is marked Yes, so my table will look like this:-

```
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
 | IsActive | IsFirstChunk | TotalResponseTime | StallTime |
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
 | Yes      | Yes          | 62                | 62        |
 | NULL     | NULL         | 327               | 0         |
 | NULL     | NULL         | 59                | 0         |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple update statement which assigns the value of `TotalResponseTime` to `StallTime` where `IsActive` and `IsFirstChunk` is `yes`

```
 update tbl set StallTime=TotalResponseTime where 
    IsActive='Yes' and IsFirstChunk='yes';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by applying condition in `where` clauses.
if IsActive and IsFirstChunk match 'yes'

```
update a1  
set stallTime = TotalResponseTime 
where IsActive in ('yes') and IsFirstChunk in ('yes');
```

another way

```
update a1  
set stallTime = TotalResponseTime 
where IsActive is not null and IsFirstChunk is not null;
```